# Kendo grid php function in template

Tags: php, function, grid, kendo-ui, var

i'm using kendo grid with PHP Wrapper ...
When formatting my column i use template, but i can't pas the #:ColmunValue# to 
the getColorForValue function.

```
<script id="ColumnTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
<div style="background-color: <?php echo '\\'.$colors->getColorForValue(#:ColmunValue#); ?   >;">
#:ColmunValue#
</div>
</script>
```

I tried a second solution:

```
$Column = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
$Column->field('ColumnName')
->title(' ')
->attributes(' bgcolor = '.getColorForValue(#: Column #) )
->templateId('ColumnTemplate')
->width(55);
```

but both are not working :(
Any Idea ?

Comment: Um! PHP runs on the server. Templates are expanded in the browser. You are mixing sides. Please, rephrase your question on what you are trying to implement and hopefully we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any PHP code in the rowTemplate (if it depends on the value of the row). You can use client expression and functions like shown [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/templates/overview).

```
<script id="ColumnTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <div style="background-color: #= someFunction(data.PersonName) #">
             #= PersonName#
     </div>
</script>
<script>
      someFunction(name){
          // some logic here and then return color based on the name
          return "red";
      }
</script>
```